# How do I split an array by the characters in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of characters:

```
var separators = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

I want to split a string by any of the characters in this array. For instance,

```
var str = 'adbasscdabda';
```

should become

```
var splitUpArray = ['d', 'ss', 'd', 'd'];
```

How do I achieve this? I have tried splitting the string by one character at a time and then concatenating the subarrays together, but this seems unwieldy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example you can use `.match` method:

```
var str = 'adbasscdabda';

str.match(/[^abc]+/g); // ["d", "ss", "d", "d"]
```

A more universal solution:

```
var separators = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var re = RegExp('[^' + separators.join('') + ']+', 'g');
var str = 'adbasscdabda';

str.match(re); // ["d", "ss", "d", "d"]
```

Comment: I was thinking about that. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

You could do one loop to replace all the characters in the first array with a set character and then do a `.split()` using that single char.   That might be simpler to maintain.

```
var separators = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 
var str = 'adbasscdabda'; 
for (var l = separators.length, i=0; i<l; i++) {
     str.replace(separators[i], '|');
}
var splitUpArray = str.split('|');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    // Array.prototype.filter must be defined.

var splitStrByChars = function( str, chars ){
    return str.split( new RegExp( "[" + chars.join('') + "]" ) ).filter(function(a){
        return a ? a : null;
    });
};

var str = "adbasscdabda";
var separators = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

console.log( splitStrByChars( str, separators ).join( ', ' ) == "d, ss, d, d" );
```

Comment: `separators.join().replace(/,/g, '')` so it's `[abc]` rather than `[a,b,c]` (?)

Comment: Thanks. separators.join('') also works. ... haha. I should have used `match` instead of `split`. oh well.